# React + Express + socket.IO on localhost does not connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am using React as client with Express as backend:

App.js:

```
const [socket] = useSocket("localhost:80");

    useEffect( () => {
        socket.emit("test", "test message");
        })
    });
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http")
const socketIO = require("socket.io")
const port = process.env.PORT || 80; // process... is an environment variable used by heroku

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../build')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../build', 'index.html'))
});

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("new client");
    }
)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Server is running and serves the app, but never fires the log confirming that client was registered. Why doesn't it register the client?

EDIT: Network panel shows constant gets (with 200) and posts (with 404):

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3uOnTh
Response: Cannot POST /socket.io/
```

EDIT2: this version works on localhost, but I have no idea why:
server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
// localhost  server port
const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;
const app = express();

// server instance
const server = http.createServer(app);

// socket with an instance of the server
const io = socketIO(server);

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("New client connected");

    socket.on("test", data => {
        console.log("test received");
        io.sockets.emit("test response", "response")
    });
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../build')));
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../build', 'index.html'))
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

App.js

```
const [socket] = useSocket("localhost:4001");

    useEffect( () => {
        socket.emit("test", "test message");
        socket.on("test response", data => {
            console.log("test response received");
            setTestData(data);
        })
    });

    function handleEmission() {
        console.log("emmitting");
        socket.emit("test", "test message");
    }
    ...
    <button onClick={() => handleEmission()}>Handle emission</button>
```

The whole code is hosted on https://github.com/faire2/loreHunters.

Comment: try with `useSocket("ws://localhost:80")`

Comment: Isn't port 80 allocated for HTTP? Not sure if that's how socket.io works or not - I'm just curious.

Comment: Changing the port to 3000 did not earn connection, nor did changing useSocket parameter to 3000.

Comment: How are you calling your socket?

Comment: Through create-react-app application, React hook useSocket.

Comment: @saglamcem yeah it defaults to port 80. Try it with another port, since you are running your node app and react on the same port. This can cause issues. Run your node app on 3000 with socket io and then react. Might be fine on server (not really) but localhost my have issues with it.

Comment: @PHPNoob I have since changed the configuration to 3000 with no change in the outcome.

Comment: Can you post your app.js file? How are you binding the ports and http with app.set() looking through the docs here: https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express

Comment: I think that I listed the relevant code (useSocket creates the connections with port 4001, useEffect runs automatically with each render, handleEmission is triggered by clicking on button). The whole App.js has 440 LOC and is ripe for refactoring. I do not think that it would really be useful to post it all here. Is there anything specific I could provide?